# R.java not getting generated in new project eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

The moment i make a new android project in eclipse I get an error in MainActivity.java R cannot be resolved to a variable.. There is no R.java file in my gen folder.. I tried clean and rebuilding but made no difference. How do I solve this error?

Comment: Try restarting eclipse.

Comment: ofcourse I did that many times

Comment: In your XML file, may be there has some error that's why its not generating the `R.java` file.

Comment: Project/Clean. And double check all your xml files for hidden errors. And I mean ALL xml files, also strings.xml and such.

Comment: How can there be an error when I havent even started coding..ALso my SDK manager does not show up

Comment: be sure not to have android.R imported

Comment: i checked that already..there is no such import

Comment: In Eclipse, under the Project menu, there's an option build automatically. Check if it is checked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to a new version of eclipse and the problem disappeared.